# Обесцвечивание картинки при наведении через JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Подскажите небольшой скрипт через JQuery или через чистый CSS для обесцвечивания картинки (сделать ее черно-белой) при наведении курсора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
img:hover {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome */
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="cat" />
```

Comment: этот пример не работает, возможно здесь что-то не так ?

Comment: добавил вендоный префикс для Chrome

Comment: а можно сделать при этом плавный переход ?

Comment: добавил `transition: 1s;`

Comment: не работает transition